# Jquery even on select

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to show/hide div on change of the select list (if has value), however the click and change event didn't work no matter. Here's the source html code:

```
<select name="iam" id="iam">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="1">Student</option>
    <option value="2">Teacher</option>
    <option value="3">Prof</option>
</select>

<div id="look"> Some text </div>



$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#iam').val().on('blur change selected', function() {
            $('#look').show();
        } else {
            $('#look').hide();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited according to your comment below: this code will check if the value selected is not the default, and if so show the "Some text" div:

```
if (!$("#iam").val()) {
    $('#look').hide();
}

$('#iam').on('change', function() {
        if ($(this).val()) {
            $('#look').show();
        } 
        else {
            $('#look').hide();
        }

    });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2befcr9h/1/)

Comment: it is working but when i select 'Please Select' and other values sometimes it is not working. Why? @Fiddle

Comment: @Newmaster I specifically made it that when you choose "Please select" it won't change, I thought you wanted it that way when you said: `(if has value)`

Comment: @Newmaster Do you want it to change no matter which option you select?

Comment: @Fiddle i want to display div when user select only 'Student or Teacher or Prof' and when user select "Please Select" hide div again

Comment: @Newmaster Please see edited answer. Also edited the fiddle, take another look.